# setBackgroundimage in UIButton using SDWebimage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I want to set the UIButton background image using SDWebImage.

Code :-

```
[btn.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"image url here"]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not really following this, sorry. What have you tried and what happens when you try it?

Comment: @Robert hi set the same image in uiimageview but in uibutton its not set i am using this methods https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIButton%2BWebCache.h

Comment: @Robert and use this link https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/117

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are method for this in SDWebImage :  [SDWebImage / SDWebImage / UIButton+WebCache.h](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h)

Import this file in your class:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h>
```

Use any of this method:

```
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
```

Comment: @Alexander Thanks to draw my attention. Can u edit Answer I will approve it.

Answer (score 4):

**You can directly set image to UIButton using SDWebImage**

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h>

 [btnProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMAGE_URL_HERE"]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Or using block**

```
[btnProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMAGE_URL_HERE"]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImage.png"] completed:
    ^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with @CRDave, but if you have to make use of the UIImageView methods for something like setImageWithPreviousCachedImageWithURL (which as of writing isn't part of the UIButton category) then don't set the button background in the completion block otherwise your placeholder or progressive loading won't work. Rather set it like this:

```
    UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [temp sd_setImageWithPreviousCachedImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl] andPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"] options:SDWebImageRetryFailed progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
        //Nothing.
    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        //Nothing.
    }];
    [btnTheButton setBackgroundImage:temp.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Seems like this method doesn't exist anymore. `setImageWithPreviousCachedImageWithURL`

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *imageViewb;
[imageViewb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"image url here"]
                               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                [button setImage: imageViewb.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
            }];
```

Comment: M.thanks for answer but this way not work i already tried this one

Answer (score 0):

if `#import <SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h>` 
is not found then i think you have to use 
**#import "UIButton+WebCache.h"** instead of 
`#import <SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h>`

This will work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this here but for sake of ease I am reposting the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616298/3904109

```
cell.bProfileImage.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string:
individualChatsListArray[indexPath.row].profile_image), for:
UIControl.State.normal, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:
"default_profile"), options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (image,
error, cache, url) in

}
```