# How to use SDWebImage to add "foreground" image to UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sdwebimage

I know there is a way to set background images for buttons using SDWebImage. But how do I set the image, i.e., foreground image? For normal state.

Comment: This question does not need to be closed anymore than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704334/setbackgroundimage-in-uibutton-using-sdwebimage. I didn't see the method. And the one with completion block was buggy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at `UIButton+webCache.h`?

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState(UIControlSTate)state;
```

is for the regular image and

```
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState(UIControlSTate)state;
```

is for the background image.